# Unable to launch jmeter plugin manager

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

[image]

I'm receiving the error as shown in the image while opening the plugin manager in jmeter.

Comment: Read the text "One of the possible reasons is that you have proxy requirement for Internet connection.", it fails to get an SSL connection

Comment: Check this one https://superuser.com/questions/1400180/jmeter-plugins-manager-failed-to-download-plugins-repository

Answer (score 1):

It means that the certification path to the JMeter Plugins repository contains invalid certificate (for example you're behind the corporate proxy and this proxy injects a [MITM certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) which is not known to Java / JMeter)

The solution would be:

1. Identify the certificate which causes the problem, it can be done using [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) tool
2. Create a [Java Truststore](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/820-3503/6nf1il6er/index.html) (the same OpenSSL tool can do this)
3. Point JMeter to use this Truststore by setting [`javax.net.ssl.trustStore` system property](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)